# How to parse SQL Queries and sub queries using sqlparser into python

Tags: python-2.7

Want to parse sql join query, select sub query into python. I am using sqlparse library. But i could not parse sub query. How i can parse whole query.

e.g:

```
query = "select id,fname,lname,address from res_users as r left join res_partner as p on p.id=r.partner_id where name = (select name from res_partner where id = 1)"

query_tokens = sqlparse.parse(query)[0].tokens
```

I could not parse for this `select name from res_partner where id = 1` sub query.

Answer (score 5):

Not so elegant, but works:

```
import sqlparse
from sqlparse.sql import Where, Comparison, Parenthesis

query = """
select
    id,fname,lname,address
from
    res_users as r
    left join
        res_partner as p
    on
        p.id=r.partner_id
where
    name = (select name from res_partner where id = 1)"""

query_tokens = sqlparse.parse(query)[0]
where = next(token for token in query_tokens.tokens if isinstance(token, Where))
condition = next(token for token in where.tokens if isinstance(token, Comparison))
subquery = next(token for token in condition.tokens if isinstance(token, Parenthesis))
print subquery
```

prints:

```
(select name from res_partner where id = 1)
```

Answer (score -1):

This library can parse and generate SQL https://code.google.com/p/python-sql/